# What might be causing all fonts I use to appear slightly smaller on waterfox than chrome, safari, and opera, and the font on IE9 to appear bolded?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

The font of my site appears identical as far as I can see on firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera. I have been using a 64 bit build of firefox, called waterfox, for a few months now. When I view the site in waterfox, both of the fonts I use appear smaller, but the rest of the content appears the exact same size as in the three above browsers. Waterfox is essentially firefox compiled with intel c++ 64 bit compiler. I have made sure all browsers are at 100% zoom, and the fonts are loaded with @fontface. Is there a way I can make the font render the same size in waterfox as it does in the others?

the site is http://www.pistol.org.ohio-state.edu

Comment: Considering the fact that you cannot expect fonts to render any specific size or guarantee the desired font-face is even available on the user's machine, does it matter?

Comment: Try setting font-size:100% on the body tag as the first thing in your style sheet. I'd also recommend loading up a css reset file before your main css file. The way you include the css and other HEAD files is mildly crazy using javascript. I've never seen that done before. It means that no one viewing your site with javascript disabled will see any of your styles etc.